# Write a SAS equation even if values are missing more elegantly

Tags: sas, missing-data

I have a dataset where I'm converting things to minutes. It looks like this:

```
  id      hours     minutes
  1        1           5
  2         .          45
  3         1          .
```

ETC

I want to convert everything to minutes so I wrote this:

```
DATA TEST;
  SET Original;
  in_minutes = 60*hours + minutes;
RUN;
```

Now I know that for missing values this returns `.` but I want it to return the correct value for example 1 would be 65 and id 2 would be 45 and id 3 would be 60.

I guess I could write:

```
DATA TEST;
  SET Original
  IF hours ^= . AND Minutes ^= . then in_minutes = 60*hours + minutes;
  ELSE IF hours ^= . THEN in_minutes = 60*hours;
  ELSE if minutes ^= . THEN in_minutes = minutes;
RUN;
```

But this seems like it could be complicated if you were doing an equation with more pieces. Is there a more elegant way to handle the missingness from equations if it isn't something like `sum` or `avg`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would convert to SAS TIME (seconds) and use coalesce function for example.

```
data time;
   input hours     minutes;
   duration = hms(coalesce(hours,0),coalesce(minutes,0),0);
   format duration hhmm8.;
   cards;
1 5
. 45
1  .
46 20
. 200
;;;;
   run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I use the fact that the `sum()` function is tolerant of missing:

```
x = sum(.,1)  => x=1

x = .;
x = sum(x,0)  => x=0
```

So try:

```
in_minutes = 60*sum(0,hours) + sum(0,minutes);
```

Comment: Oh I like that! That is clever.

Comment: If you have to include 0, it works more like coalesce() than the sum() function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `SUM()` function to perform addition even with some missing values.

```
in_minutes = sum(60*hours,minutes);
```

You will still get a missing value if both HOURS and MINUTES are missing.

You could add another `SUM()` function call (or a `COALESCE()` function call) to eliminate the warning about generating missing values when HOURS is missing.

```
in_minutes = sum(60*sum(hours,0),minutes);
```

But this will mean that if both are missing you will get 0 instead of missing.  You could add more logic to only perform the calculation when at least one of the values exists.

```
if n(hours,minutes) then in_minutes = sum(60*sum(hours,0),minutes);
```

Comment: Doesn't the first one still generate messages to the log about missing values?

Comment: Sure it generates message, but it doesn't generate actual missing values unless both HOURS and MINUTES are missing, unlike the `+` operator.